# 2d interpolation in R vs. Matlab

Tags: c++, r, matlab, interpolation

I recently needed to convert a lot of Matlab code to R. 2-d interpolation on a regular grid is the biggest time sink in this code relative to Matlab - in R the interpolation takes ~35x longer. I need to run this over 200k times so speed is important. I have many other things going on in the loop for my code, so I need to retain this structure.

To get an idea I run this

```
for (i in 1 : 1000) {
    Z_New <- interpp(x,y,Z[,,i],znew,ynew,linear=TRUE)
 }
```

The first 3 lines output from profiler are

```
$by.self
                  self.time self.pct total.time total.pct
".Fortran"            11.46    86.17      11.46     86.17
"paste"                1.60    12.03       1.60     12.03
".makeMessage"         0.04     0.30       0.08      0.60

$by.total
                       total.time total.pct self.time self.pct
"interpp"                   13.30    100.00      0.02     0.15
"interpp.old"               13.28     99.85      0.02     0.15
".Fortran"                  11.46     86.17     11.46    86.17
```

I do the same in Matlab

```
tic
for i=1:1000         
        Z_New = interp2(x, y, Z(:,:,i),  xnew, ynew, 'linear');        
end
toc
Elapsed time is 0.387968 seconds.
```

Is this a limitation of the language, or is there some way to do this more efficiently in R?

**Update 31-03-17: Minimal working example**

```
library(akima)
library(fields)
data(lennon)
n.coarse <- 30
x <-1:n.coarse
y <-1:n.coarse
z<-lennon[ 201:(200+n.coarse), 201:(200+n.coarse)]
# sample at n.fine x n.fine equally spaced points on a grid
n.fine <- 100
xnew <- seq( 1,n.coarse,,n.fine)
ynew <- seq( 1,n.coarse,,n.fine)
# reshape data
z_1 <- as.vector(t(z))
x_1 <- rep(x,times=1,each=n.coarse)
y_1 <- rep(y,n.coarse)

Rprof(tmp <- tempfile())
for (i in 1 : 10000) {
  interp(x_1,y_1,z_1,xnew,ynew,linear=TRUE)
}
Rprof()
summaryRprof(tmp)

# I would like to send data to matlab to compare
library(R.matlab)
outR <- interp(x_1,y_1,z_1,xnew,ynew,linear=TRUE)
writeMat("m_out.mat",x=x,y=y,z=z,xnew=xnew,ynew=ynew,outR=outR$z )
```

It takes 46s on my laptop, I now run this in matlab

```
load m_out
x=double(x);
y=double(y);
tic
for i=1:10000
interp2(x, y, z', xnew,ynew', 'linear');
end
toc

% let's have a look at the results
out = interp2(x, y, z', xnew,ynew', 'linear')';
[xs ys] = meshgrid(xnew,ynew);
% from matlab
surf(xs,ys,out)
% from R
surf(xs,ys,outR)
% differences
err = outR-out;
surf(xs,ys,err)

Elapsed time is 2.720706 seconds.
```

As pointed out, R is calling Fortran to do the interpolation. Matlab is using more than one core to process this request as well, which will explain some of the difference. I have been looking into the Rcpp package, but have no experience with C++, so it will take me some time. Any tips, or reasons why I should/should not be able to speed this up?

Comment: `interp2` MATLAB function is for interpolation of `regular` data .

Comment: From the matlab help for interp2 - All the interpolation methods require that X and Y be monotonic and
    plaid (as if they were created using MESHGRID).  If you provide two
    monotonic vectors, interp2 changes them to a plaid internally.
    X and Y can be non-uniformly spaced.

Comment: they can be non-uniformly spaced but make a regular(rectangular) grid  instead of tessellation of randomly spaced points. Here is an example of a [regular grid](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/7bf715b097c139d34792c25936690753)

Comment: You should use a R function that applies interpolation on regular grid.

Comment: I think [interp.surface](https://www.image.ucar.edu/GSP/Software/Fields/Help/interp.surface.html) can help.

Comment: I tried interp.surface.grid, and it's even a little slower than what I have above

Comment: As you see, the time is mostly spend in Fortran code. There is nothing R can do about that. However, there might be packages with faster implementations. You should provide a reproducible example.

Comment: I am editing out the Rcpp tag. This has nothing to do with Rcpp, apart from the fact that you wish someone wrote code for you.  Which isn't a suitable StackOverflow request.

Comment: I added the tag for Rcpp because I don't even know if this is something that is feasible with rcpp. If it is I'm happy to start trying to code it, but if there is some reason that I cannot I would like to hear about it before I invest a lot of time trying to do it. Hence the tag, and the question, that asked about feasibility, not for anyone to write the code for me.